# Select2 in django doesn't show the options

Tags: django, django-forms, jquery-select2

I want to join selections in a form.
I have the model "Country" and the model "City".
when a user selects a Country only the Cities listed in that country should be listed.

The problem is that When I try to do it, in the form I cant see any options, so no country or cities are listed at all.

This is my code:

forms.py:

> Blockquote

```
    from django import forms
    from django.forms import ModelForm
    from .models import Country, City
    from django_select2.forms import ModelSelect2Widget



     class AddressForm(forms.Form):
         country = forms.ModelChoiceField(
         queryset=Comunidad.objects.all(),
         label=u"Country",
         widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
         dependent_fields={'city': 'city'},
         search_fields=['name__icontains'],
    
          )
         )

    city = forms.ModelChoiceField(
             queryset=City.objects.all(),
             label=u"City",
     widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
    
      search_fields=['name__icontains'],
    
        max_results=500,
     )
    )
```

''''''

This is what I have in models.py:

```
    class Country (models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=20, help_text="Añada Comunidad Autónoma")

    def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class City(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=20, help_text="Añada provincia")
    country = models. ForeignKey('Country', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
'''
```

and, in the template:

```
'''{{form.as_table}}'''
```

What I get is the text: "Country" and "City" followed by a drop down button but it's empty. So I see no Countries and no Cities at all, but database is not empty.

I don't know what am I missing. Any help will be welcome.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are looking for a dependent drop down. Check this link out https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to do.  I thought it would be easier to do it with Select2, but as it is not working, I will take your suggestion and do  it with AJAX.  Thanks a lot.